# Why does cal function always return true value?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

When input is pos expecting that cal function return false. But cal function alaways return true.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool cal(string s)
{
    int l=s.size();
    if(l==1)
        return false;
    int l2=l/2;
    if(l%2==0)
    {
        string s1=s.substr (0,l2);
        string s2=s.substr(l2,l2);
        if(s1==s2)
            return true;
        cal(s1);
        cal(s2);
    }
    else
    {
        string s1=s.substr (0,l2);
        string s2=s.substr(l2+1,l2);
        if(s1==s2)
            return true;
        cal(s1);
        cal(s2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        bool a;
        a=cal(s);
        if(a==true)
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your compiler warned you that not all control paths have a return.

Comment: Incidentally, since `cal()`'s `if...else` statement only differs by a single line, that's the only line that actually needs to be controlled by it.  See [here](http://ideone.com/kQpJtn) for an example of what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

In two of your logic paths, you call **cal(s1)** and discard the value, then call **cal(s2)** and similarly ignore the return value.  Thus, what you return is something you did not explicitly order; I expect that it's the incidental value of **cal(s2)**.

What did you intend for those branches where s1 != s2 ?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do; the stunted variable names and lack of comments leave us guessing about your intended action.  Why should *pos* (whatever you mean by that) input return false?

Also, there may be a logic error in your code.  It appears that you're trying to split a string in half; do you intend to lose the middle character of an odd-length string?

```
    string s1=s.substr (0,l2);
    string s2=s.substr(l2+1,l2);
```

Comment: There does appear to be a flaw with his logic, but it's not that it takes `l2` as the second subscript.  `substr()`'s second parameter is the substring's desired length, and both `l` and `l2` should have the same result.  The flaw, though, is that [if the string has an odd number of bytes, the middle byte will be ignored](http://ideone.com/kQpJtn).

Comment: You're welcome.  Hmm... by "When input is pos", I _think_ he means when the input is literally "pos".  If it's "pos", then `cal(s1)` (and also `cal(s2)`, if dropping the middle character was intentional) will be `false`; maybe he intends for `cal()` to return `false` if either of the recursive calls returns `false`?  Just a guess, I can't say for certain.